# I cant send email From Python

Tags: python

Hey Guys i am getting error while trying to send emails from python.
Error I get: socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

```
import smtplib

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smpt.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('my_email@gmail.com', 'my_password')
smtpObj.sendmail('my_email@gmail.com', 'my_email@gmail.com', 'Subject: Hey\nSent from Python.')
smtpObj.quit()
```

I have enabled gmail's less secure apps but it is still showing error!

Comment: Typo in SMTP :)

Comment: Yeah sorry guys thankyou so much

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your URL. It should read smtp not smpt.